# Unable to get webpage contents with unicode character using python 3

Tags: unicode, python3

I am trying to read a webpage of particular tag using python3 but due to unable to handle unicode character its getting error as `UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u201c' in position 145: ordinal not in range(256)` How do i use correct syntax so that i will get the tags

here is my MWE which i tried so far

```
import requests


page = requests.get("https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis+35&version=NIV")

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
story = soup.find_all('p') # to extract story title including <h3> tags
periods = [pt.get_text() for pt in story] # extract only data from <h3> tags
print (periods)
```

Comment: `export PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF8` or specify encoding inside your script.

Comment: How to specify encoding inside the script @Panki